# have Django handle oddly-encoded information in the database?

Tags: django, encoding

My Django app works with a database that is very lax in enforcing any encoding rules.  That causes problems when someone stores something like an emdash in the database (which is 0x97 in the Windows-1252 character set).  When my Django app tries to load that data and render it as utf-8, it raises DjangoUnicodeDecodeError, because the 0x97 is not a valid utf-8 byte sequence (it appears to be a continuation instruction).

Has anyone got a clever way of catching these errors and fixing them?  The database accepts data from a variety of different applications, so I can't be sure that they will play nice and only put reasonable stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database collation and charset support the characters you plan or allow to use.
For example in MySQL you need something like below:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

More details on how to change the collation and charset in MySQL below:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-database.html

Comment: except that the database in question is not MySQL.  It's some legacy thing.